# How to insert a search function into an array

Tags: java, android, json, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to create an app that will show the train name along with the train number.

Here is an example I use: [Bakerloo Line](https://api.tfl.gov.uk/line/bakerloo/arrivals)

I am trying to insert a search function and I'm not sure how to get it working.

At the moment I am using an IF statement to try and filter the data by line number. It works sorta...

I get the relevant `timeToStation`. However the `currentLocation` and `towards` stay the same as the first item searched.

```js
package com.example.devan.tfldriver_advanced;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.sql.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class linesactivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    private RequestQueue mQueue;
    
    //Global declaration
    String linename,result;
    TextView spinnerview;

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_lines);
            TextView mTextview = findViewById(R.id.lines);

            //Uline will change to each specific line
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            linename = intent.getStringExtra("Uline");

            //Produces title
            String Title = linename;
            Title = Title.replaceAll("_", " ");
            mTextview.setText(Title + " Line");

            Intent b = getIntent();
            int a = b.getIntExtra("Ustation",-1);


            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, a, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);


            mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

            //the parse is the update button
            Button button_parse = findViewById(R.id.button_parse);

            //when the button is clicked run the following method
            button_parse.setOnClickListener(newView.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    jsonParse();
            }
        });
    }

    private void jsonParse() {

        String url = "https://api.tfl.gov.uk/line/" + linename + "/arrivals";

        JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                //the user enters the train number
                EditText train_number;
                train_number = findViewById(R.id.train_number);
                String str = train_number.getText().toString();
                String sta = spinnerview.getText().toString();
                String emty = train_number.getText().toString();
                try {
                    TextView mTextViewResult;
                    mTextViewResult = findViewById(R.id.text_view_result);
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject x = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        String vehicleId = x.getString("vehicleId");
                        String currentLocation = x.getString("currentLocation");
                        String towards = x.getString("towards");
                        Integer timeToStation = x.getInt("timeToStation");
                        if (vehicleId.equals(str)) {
                            mTextViewResult.append(" Train number " + vehicleId + "\n" + " Currently location " + currentLocation + "\n" + " going to " + towards + " in " + timeToStation / 60 + " min" + "\n\n");
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        mQueue.add(request);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(final AdapterView<?> parent,View view, int i, long l) {
        result = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        spinnerview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.spinnerview);
        spinnerview.setText(result);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }
}
```

Comment: add `break;` if u find it, cos it seem loop to end, and what is your `b.getIntExtra("Ustation",-1);` content?

Comment: b.getIntExtra("Ustation",-1); is for the data for the spinner in the activity. I am using a Intent on the previous activitys on the previous activity:

The previous activity:

opencentralintent.putExtra ("Ustation",R.array.centralstations);

The data:

    <string-array name="bakerloostations">
        <item></item>,
        <item>Elephant And Castle</item>,
        <item>Lambeth North</item>,
   </string-array>

Comment: what i mean is logcat this `b.getIntExtra("Ustation",-1);` item to make sure its right, if ur `vehicleId.equals(str)` return different based on your json data it should return different `currentLocation` and `towards` and `mTextViewResult.append` replace with `mTextViewResult.setText`, just to make sure result are clean one